# My Flask app is not properly serving videos on raspberry, but normally on my laptop

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I've got flask server for streaming movies. Everything works fine while server runs on normal computer (laptop with arch) but when raspberry serves the video (using flask's static folder) I'm unable to skip (forced to watch sequentially), so when I close browser in middle of movie I have to watch it all over again, that's pretty annoying.
I'm using just `<video>` tag with `<source>` linked to static `.mp4` file served by flask.

I don't know if this could be cause by just fact that raspberry cannot stream full HD video properly, but when I'm watching sequentially I have no issues.

Whole project is on GitHub so If you want to look at the code:

"movie player" template is [here](https://github.com/JanKaifer/My_Server/blob/master/server/blueprints/video_player/templates/video_player_main.html)

code that generates that "movie player" html is [here](https://github.com/JanKaifer/My_Server/blob/master/server/blueprints/video_player/__init__.py)

Thanks for any suggestions.

PS: I have got rapsberry 3 model B and movies are stored on 4TB NTFS HDD.

EDIT: Tried 8GB Fat32 USB stick and still same problem.

Requested minimal working example:

HTML - part of `video_player_main.html`

```
<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" style="margin: auto; display: block;">
    <source src="{{ url_for("static", filename="movies/%s" % filename) }}" type="video/mp4">
    Get better browser!!!
</video>
```

Flask generating website

```
@video_player.route("/play/<path:movie>")
def play(movie):
    return render_template("video_player_main.html", filename=movie)
```

HDD with movies is mounted on ./static/movies/

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'm facing the same issue of being forced to watch sequentially my videos. I'm using python simple http.server in a raspberry pi zero. I thought it could be a performance limitation, but you are facing the same issue with rasp3 and flask, so the root cause must be somewhere else...

Comment: I haven't - I'm now using raspberry just for downloading. If you find a solution please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

What MIME type is being returned by the Flask server for the static movie files in each case?  Use the `wget` command (or something similar) to see what's being returned.

You are likely getting different MIME types on the different systems, which is causing your browser to handle the video streams slightly differently.  Note that the browser doesn't care about the file extension; it goes by the MIME type returned by the server.

Flask uses the `mimetype` Python library to figure out what MIME type to use, based on the file extension.  It uses a bunch of local files to make guesses, see:  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/mimetypes.py#L40